# Is there a standard library/API/tool for implementing basic "rule chains" in Java?

Tags: java

I am writing a servlet that will be conditionally modifying HTTP headers according to some user-definable rules. (**Edit: these rules are defined in an XML file that is read at start-up.**) For example, add "X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1" to a response header if it does not already exist and if the request specified a "User-Agent" header matching a known pattern. Not having any better ideas, I attempted to make my own POJOs representing these rules. It "works" but I feel like there must be a more standard or more flexible way to do this.

Are there general-purpose libraries or tools (whether built-in or 3rd-party) that would solve this problem? I have heard and read a little about "rules engines" but they seem like much more complex/heavy tools not meant for problems as simple as mine.

To illustrate what I'm trying to do, I've created a simplified program that applies "rules" to numbers based on "conditions" like "is an even number". Here it is, sorry it's a bit lengthy.

### Main.java

```
package my.example;

import java.util.*;

import my.example.conditions.*;
import my.example.rules.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Some sample objects to evaluate
        Collection<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        print(numbers);
        
        // Define rules
        Collection<Rule<Integer>> rules = new ArrayList<Rule<Integer>>();
        rules.add(createRuleToMultiplyEvenNumbersBy4());
        rules.add(createRuleToAdd1ToEveryNumber());
        
        // Process the rules for each sample object
        Collection<Integer> newNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
            Integer newNumber = number;
            for (Rule<Integer> rule : rules)
                newNumber = rule.apply(newNumber);
            newNumbers.add(newNumber);
        }

        print(newNumbers);
    }

    private static Rule<Integer> createRuleToMultiplyEvenNumbersBy4() {
        MultiplyNumberRule rule = new MultiplyNumberRule(true, 4);
        rule.addCondition(new NumberIsEvenCondition());
        return rule;
    }
    
    private static Rule<Integer> createRuleToAdd1ToEveryNumber() {
        AddNumberRule rule = new AddNumberRule(true, 1);
        rule.addCondition(new ConstantCondition<Integer>(true));
        return rule;
    }
    
    private static void print(Collection<Integer> numbers) {
        System.out.print("Numbers: ");
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
            System.out.print(number);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\r\n");
    }   
    

}
```

### Condition.java

```
package my.example.conditions;

public interface Condition<T> {
    boolean appliesTo(T obj);
}
```

### ConstantCondition.java

```
package my.example.conditions;

public class ConstantCondition<T> implements Condition<T> {
    private boolean constant;
    
    public ConstantCondition(boolean alwaysReturnThisValue) {
        constant = alwaysReturnThisValue;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(T target) {
        return constant;
    }
}
```

### NumberIsEvenCondition.java

```
package my.example.conditions;

public class NumberIsEvenCondition implements Condition<Integer> {
    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(Integer i) {
        return (i % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

### Rule.java

```
package my.example.rules;

public interface Rule<T> {
    T apply(T target);
}
```

### AbstractRule.java

```
package my.example.rules;

import java.util.*;

import my.example.conditions.Condition;
public abstract class AbstractRule<T> implements Rule<T> {
    private Collection<Condition<T>> conditions;
    private boolean requireAllConditions;
    
    public AbstractRule(boolean requireAllConditions) {
        conditions = new ArrayList<Condition<T>>();
        this.requireAllConditions = requireAllConditions;
    }

    public void addCondition(Condition<T> condition) {
        conditions.add(condition);
    }

    @Override
    public T apply(T target) {
        boolean isApplicable;
        if (requireAllConditions)
            isApplicable = allConditionsSatisfied(target);
        else
            isApplicable = atLeastOneConditionSatisfied(target);
        
        if (isApplicable)
            target = process(target);
        
        return target;
    }
    
    // Check if all conditions are met
    protected boolean allConditionsSatisfied(T target) {
        for (Condition<T> condition : conditions) {
            if (!condition.appliesTo(target))
                return false;
        }       
        return true;
    }
    
    // Check if any conditions are met
    protected boolean atLeastOneConditionSatisfied(T target) {
        for (Condition<T> condition : conditions) {
            if (condition.appliesTo(target))
                return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }

    abstract T process(T target);

}
```

### AddNumberRule.java

```
package my.example.rules;

public class AddNumberRule extends AbstractRule<Integer> {
    private Integer addend;
    
    public AddNumberRule(boolean requireAllConditions) {
        this(requireAllConditions, 0);
    }
    
    public AddNumberRule(boolean requireAllConditions, Integer addend) {
        super(requireAllConditions);
        this.addend = addend;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Integer process(Integer i) {
        return i + addend;
    }
}
```

### MultiplyNumberRule.java

```
package my.example.rules;

public class MultiplyNumberRule extends AbstractRule<Integer> {
    private Integer factor;
    
    public MultiplyNumberRule(boolean requireAllConditions) {
        this(requireAllConditions, 1);
    }
    
    public MultiplyNumberRule(boolean requireAllConditions, Integer factor) {
        super(requireAllConditions);
        this.factor = factor;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Integer process(Integer i) {
        return i * factor;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I feel like there must be a more standard or more flexible way to do this" - that's begging the question. To me this doesn't seem like a requirement common enough and generalisable enough (short of an actual programming language) to make a library likely. Personally I'd have the user write snippets of Javascript - the Rhino engine should be available in the JDK.

Comment: @millimoose, perhaps it's not common enough, but I was thinking of how frequently rule chains like this appear in software. For example, firewall rules, file permissions, audio/image/video effects processing, etc. Using a JavaScript file is an interesting idea, but for my case I think it would be overkill. I've tried to update the question to clarify the configuration part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd use [Commons Chain](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-chain/)

> A popular technique for organizing the execution of complex processing
>   flows is the "Chain of Responsibility" pattern, as described (among
>   many other places) in the classic "Gang of Four" design patterns book.
>   Although the fundamental API contracts required to implement this
>   design patten are extremely simple, it is useful to have a base API
>   that facilitates using the pattern, and (more importantly) encouraging
>   composition of command implementations from multiple diverse sources.

it's a common Design Pattern, guess that fits your problem

Comment: Thanks; I'm checking it out now. It doesn't look like it's been updated  for a number of years, but I suppose the pattern is much older. To my shame, I never learned about design patterns until now (started reading GOF book along w/ Robert Martin's "Clean Code"), so I've got a lot of catching-up to do.

Comment: Luiz, please take a look at [my attempt to use commons-chain][#answer-18322281] and let me know how it is different than what you are suggesting. It's not clear to me how to use it to simplify my original example. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any problem...what's wrong with your new version?

Comment: Well, it's not "wrong" just as the original isn't "wrong" but it seems like commons-chain isn't adding any value. Some would say it made the program worse, for example, because commons-chain doesn't use generics I had to do some extra casting and suppress the corresponding warnings.  Also, the "conditions" part of the program is unchanged. Perhaps there is a way that I should be using commons-chain to deal with the conditions too?

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, but you are using commons-chain correctly. Reading your source once, guess that commons-chain really doesn't fit your context nor your needs...and you're right, the current rules engines like drools, are too much for your case...I came up with commons chain, but your case is a little specific. When it comes to rules, there aren't a pattern or something.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It's helpful to at least know that I'm not missing an obvious solution and "reinventing the wheel" needlessly. If no one offers a better answer in the next week I will mark yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: smooth! hahaha glad that I could "help" in some way or another

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the original code attempting to use [Commons Chain](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-chain/), but it doesn't seem much different. Luiz E., is this roughly what you are suggesting? It seems like commons-chain does not include any notion of "conditions" -- this is left to the user as part of the implementation of `Command`.

### Main.java

```
package my.example;

import java.util.*;

import org.apache.commons.chain.*;
import org.apache.commons.chain.impl.*;

import my.example.commands.*;
import my.example.conditions.*;

public class Main {

    private static final String NUMBERS = "numbers";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Some sample objects to evaluate
        Context context = new ContextBase();
        setNumbersInContext(context, Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));
        printNumbersFromContext(context);

        // Define rules
        Chain ruleChain = new ChainBase();
        ruleChain.addCommand(new MultiplyNumberCommand(4, new NumberIsEvenCondition()));
        ruleChain.addCommand(new AddNumberCommand(1));

        // Process the rules
        ruleChain.execute(context);
        printNumbersFromContext(context);
    }

    private static void printNumbersFromContext(Context context) {
        Collection<Integer> numbers = getNumbersFromContext(context);
        System.out.print("Numbers: ");
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
            System.out.print(number);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\r\n");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Collection<Integer> getNumbersFromContext(Context context) {
        Object obj = context.get(NUMBERS);
        try {
            return (Collection<Integer>) obj;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Context did not contain the required data. ClassCastException message is: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }   

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void setNumbersInContext(Context context, Collection<Integer> numbers) {
        context.put(NUMBERS, numbers);
    }   


}
```

### AbstractNumberCommand.java

```
package my.example.commands;

import static my.example.Main.getNumbersFromContext;
import static my.example.Main.setNumbersInContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import my.example.conditions.Condition;

import org.apache.commons.chain.*;

public abstract class AbstractNumberCommand implements Command {

    private boolean continueProcessing = true;
    protected Condition<Integer> condition;

    protected AbstractNumberCommand(Condition<Integer> condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public void continueProcessing(boolean continueProcessing) {
        this.continueProcessing = continueProcessing;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(Context context) throws Exception {
        Collection<Integer> numbers = getNumbersFromContext(context);
        Collection<Integer> newNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int number : numbers)
            if (condition.appliesTo(number))
                newNumbers.add(modifyNumber(number));
            else
                newNumbers.add(number);
        setNumbersInContext(context, newNumbers);

        if (continueProcessing)
            return CONTINUE_PROCESSING;
        else
            return PROCESSING_COMPLETE;
    }

    protected abstract int modifyNumber(int number);
}
```

### AddNumberCommand.java

```
package my.example.commands;

import my.example.conditions.*;

public class AddNumberCommand extends AbstractNumberCommand {

    private int addend;

    public AddNumberCommand() {
        this(0);
    }

    public AddNumberCommand(int addend) {
        this(addend, new ConstantCondition<Integer>(true));
    }

    public AddNumberCommand(int addend, Condition<Integer> condition) {
        super(condition);
        this.addend = addend;
    }

    @Override
    protected int modifyNumber(int number) {
        return number + addend;
    }
}
```

### Condition.java

```
package my.example.conditions;

public interface Condition<T> {
    boolean appliesTo(T obj);
}
```

### ConstantCondition.java

```
package my.example.conditions;

public class ConstantCondition<T> implements Condition<T> {
    private boolean constant;

    public ConstantCondition(boolean alwaysReturnThisValue) {
        constant = alwaysReturnThisValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(T target) {
        return constant;
    }
}
```

### NumberIsEvenCondition.java

```
package my.example.conditions;

public class NumberIsEvenCondition implements Condition<Integer> {
    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(Integer i) {
        return (i % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```